# Web forms inline syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, forms, syntax-highlighting

I work on an application that reads JavaScript code as input. The code is entered using an HTML form.

Is there a way to dynamically syntax-highlight the code to improve readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You'll have to use a JavaScript library to provide a code editor.  We recently used [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/) and it worked pretty well.